# android programming - postpone alarm manager's pending intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent, android-alarms

I am actually writing a reminder android application. I am able to create reminders using the alarm manager and pending intents, but I am not sure how to postpone them.

Here is how I create a reminder...

```
AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) c.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Inent notificationIntent = new Intent(c, ReminderAlert.class);
notificationIntent.putExtra("REM_NAME",remName );
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(c, a unique id for the reminder, notificationIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,remTime, pi);
```

I am able to get the intent used in the pending intent...

How would I postpone the alarm manager and pending intent to a new time (as a long)?

Answer (score 0):

Set a brand new alarm for the new time.

Comment: I tried that, but the pending intent isn't getting called. I think it's because I use the same id for that reminder in the pendingintent.getbroadcast

Comment: Have you tested that theory?  Set a new id just to see if it worked?  Because if it does, you could use a new id and then just update the id in whatever data structure you're using to store alarms.

Comment: Okay, I'll do that. Thanks for your help Gabe!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Cfreak Yes it does.  A different approach to a problem is always an acceptable answer.  Please pay more attention when doing reviews.

Comment: Agreed. Valid answer. Could use some elaboration, perhaps.